# NASM assembly jump if equal function

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am very new to assembly programming and just writing small easy programs and doing lots of tutorials to try and teach myself. I spend most of my day using bash and python but assembly has  a big advantage in my area of work plus I am fascinated by it to no end.

I am writing a small program to take user input of 'y' or 'n' compare it and output one of 2 messages. Its pretty straight forward however I am unable to figure out where my jump logic is failing and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction.

I am using NASM in windows 7 x64, this code compiles without an issue and I have traced the issue back to my jump instructions. Below is my code. My problem is that after entering y or n it does not seem to be calling yes_msg or no_msg properly and after an afternoon on google and on here I've been unable to figure it out. If anyone could help I'd be very grateful.

Thanks.

```
;compile with nasm.exe -f elf tutorial4.asm
;gcc -m32 tutorial4.o -o tutorial4.exe


global _main
extern _printf
extern _scanf
global _yes_msg
global _no_msg


section .data
msg db "Please say yes or no? [y/n] ", 0
msgy db "You said yes! ", 0
msgn db "You said no! ", 0
yes db 'y', 0
no db 'n', 0
fmt db "%s", 0          


section .bss            
inpt resb 200           


section .text           

_yes_msg: 
    push msgy
    call _printf
    add esp, 4

_no_msg: 
    push msgn
    call _printf
    add esp, 4

_main:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp        

    push msg            
    call _printf        
    add esp, 4          

    push inpt           
    push fmt
    call _scanf         
    mov eax, inpt
    mov edx, 'y'
    cmp eax, edx
    jne _no_msg
    jmp _yes_msg
    add esp, 8          

    mov esp, ebp 
    pop ebp
ret
```

Comment: Please paste your code here so we know what you have tried

Comment: Sorry about that I made a few mistakes formatting, I have never posted here before :D.

Answer (score 1):

First, scanf returns number of processed entries (it will reside in eax). Check it, 0 means scanf rejected to parse (and you can't check the buffer because it could keep some garbage - according to NASM documentation, `resb` provides uninitialized storage, which can be filled, for example, with runtime loader temporary values). You should rely on buffer contents only if scanf returned 1.

Second, your comparing deals with 4-byte values in eax and edx. Again, even if `mov edx,'y'` fills it with 0x00000075, you can't be sure eax contains only the lowest significant byte. Call `cmp al, dl` instead.

(BTW, your _yes_msg, _no_msg miss returning to main, and it will print "You said yes!" and then "You said no!" on 'y'. Is it intentional?)

Comment: Thanks Netch, got the code working now with a few minor changes you suggested. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your instruction `mov eax, inpt` moves the *address* of the buffer at *inpt* in the EAX register. You need the first byte at this location, so you have to write `mov al, [inpt]`. Remember this is NASM!

Now you can compare the contents:

```
mov dl, 'y'
cmp al, dl
```

You placed the clean-up for your call to _scanf below an absolute jump and thus it will never be executed. Move it up to just under the call itself:

```
call _scanf
add esp, 8
mov al, [inpt]
```

As @Netch said you should probably change the codes at *_yes_msg* and *_no_msg* because now you get both messages in a row and additionally don't exit the program like it should.

Comment: Cheers for that, both you and Netch helped me see a few floors I had not considered. Thanks again fro your help.